# Adding # character to solr search query is converting my solr json to xml. How do i fix?

Tags: c#, json, xml, solr, special-characters

I am having an issue with special characters in my Solr query... specifically the pound sign (#) when added to the Solr search string... Example, searching for 'C#'.

First I am building my URL dependent upon what the user is searching/faceting on.

```
private string GetURLFromSearch(string search)
{
    string begin = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SolrURI"] + "select?q=";
    string query = search + "*";
    string fq = "";
    ...
    string end = String.Format(
          "&start=0&rows=" + rowsToDisplay + "&wt=json&indent=true&json.nl=map&defType=edismax&qf=acronym^100+cde_project_name^4+cde_description^2+text&facet=true&facet.field="
           ...
           ...
    );
    return begin + query + /*afterQuery + functionRollup +*/ fq + end;
}
```

I pass the URL I am building to:

```
private string GetJSONFromURL(string url)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        return wc.DownloadString(url);
    }
}
```

But when searching "C#", GetJSONFromURL returns XML instead of JSON. I am not sure why this is.

I have tried changing "C#" -> "C%23"
I have also looked into changing the tokenizer in the schema.. but that is a change I am trying to avoid as I believe it would effect many other aspects of our search.

schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "I have tried changing "C#" -> "C%23" - and what did that do? That sounds like the right fix to me, given that `#` has a specific meaning here...

Comment: Could  you please paste an xml error?

Comment: Changing the string to "c%23" works half way as it is returning JSON which is what I want but does not return any search results (which is wrong). So it can query now on something it can interpret which is a start.

Comment: there never was an XML error. querying on "c#" was returning XML instead of JSON even with "&wt=json" in the URL

Comment: Have you tried to escape "#" sign?